# Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported, when I try to run my camera coding

Tags: ios, swift, camera

When I try to run my camera coding I receive following error message

> "2019-05-09 23:15:48.446844+0200 testing2[514:31963] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureSession addInput:] Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb) "

I can't find out where the problem occurs and have tried with breakpoint to get to know but didn't manage.

Have also tried solutions with info.plist so it dosn't have anything with that to do.

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

var previewLayer:CALayer!

var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!

var takePhoto = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    prepareCamera()
}


func prepareCamera() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices
    captureDevice = availableDevices.first
    beginSession()


}

func beginSession () {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

    }catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    self.previewLayer = previewLayer
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
    captureSession.startRunning()

    let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]

    dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
    }

    captureSession.commitConfiguration()


    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.brianadvent.captureQueue")
    dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)





}

@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    takePhoto = true

}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if takePhoto {
        takePhoto = false

        if let image = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer) {

            let photoVC =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:  nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoVC") as! Viewcontroller2

            photoVC.takenPhoto = image

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(photoVC, animated: true, completion: {
                    self.stopCaptureSession()
                })

            }
        }


    }
}


func getImageFromSampleBuffer (buffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
    if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer) {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        let context = CIContext()

        let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))

        if let image = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: imageRect) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .right)
        }

    }

    return nil
}

func stopCaptureSession () {
    self.captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
        for input in inputs {
            self.captureSession.removeInput(input)
        }
    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



















struct Constants {
    static let apiKey = "AIzaSyDtaJ5eU24rbnHsG9pb1STOizDJvqcaj5E"
    static let bundleId = "com.felibundle"
    static let searchEngineId = "016628067786358079133:2gm9usqzouc"
}
@IBAction func pish(_ sender: Any) {
    googleSearch(term: "George Bush") { results in
        print(results)}
}
func googleSearch(term: String, callback:@escaping ([(title: String, url: String)]?) -> Void) {
    let urlString = String(format: "https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=016628067786358079133:2gm9usqzouc", term, Constants.searchEngineId, Constants.apiKey)
    let encodedUrl = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

    guard let url = URL(string: encodedUrl ?? urlString) else {
        print("invalid url \(urlString)")
        return
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(Constants.bundleId, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let datatask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard
            error == nil,
            let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]
            else {

                callback(nil)
                return
        }

        guard let items = json?["items"] as? [[String : Any]], items.count > 0 else {
            print("no results")
            return
        }

        callback(items.map { ($0["title"] as! String, $0["formattedUrl"] as! String) })
    }


    datatask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   prepareCamera()
}
```

is called multiple times when you present a vc above the current vc and dismiss it , so you may put it inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: i guess you do a segue / present to return to camera vc while you should do a pop/dismiss inside `viewController2`

Comment: How do you return from `viewController2` to `viewController`

Comment: I show the image that has been taken in Viewcontroller in Viewcontroller2 through segue- @Sh_Khan

Comment: but this `self.present(photoVC, animated: true, completion: {` isn't a segue , it's a present , How do you return form 2 ????

Comment: But how should I do instead then? I still have the error that I told about in the question@Sh_Khan

Comment: move from vc1 to vc2 is ok , but from vc2 to vc1 do `self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)`

Comment: That solved it! Now when I got you on the line.. When I have taken the picture, I can't show it on second viewcontroller instead it appears a moving image of what my camera shows. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

this should fix the issue....

```
if captureSession.inputs.isEmpty {
    self.captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
}
```

Comment: Ive already got this in my code, but with (input) and I still get the same error message